# How to get all the photos stored in iPhone to NSArray using Photo Framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I want to show my photos from iPhone to `UICollectionViewController` How can I get all the pictures stored in device to NSArray? Or some Array or Set from which I am able to retrieve image array? I want to use something like [PhotoFramework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014408) or some latest way to do it. Please dont post Asset Library answers since Apple stated that:

> IMPORTANT
>
> In iOS 8.0 and later, use the Photos framework instead of the Assets
>   Library framework. The Photos framework provides more features and
>   better performance for working with a user’s photo library. See Photos
>   Framework Reference.

Comment: You should visit this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633843/get-all-of-the-pictures-from-an-iphone-photolibrary-in-an-array-using-assetslibr

Comment: @C_X I have read that Photo Framework is better to use than assetlibrary.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by us `ALassetLibray` for more detail You should visit this link  [Get all of the pictures from an iPhone photoLibrary in an array using AssetsLibrary framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633843/get-all-of-the-pictures-from-an-iphone-photolibrary-in-an-array-using-assetslibr)

**Using Photos Framework**
[iOS 8 Photos framework: Get a list of all albums with iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981374/ios-8-photos-framework-get-a-list-of-all-albums-with-ios8)

Comment: "IMPORTANT

In iOS 8.0 and later, use the Photos framework instead of the Assets Library framework. The Photos framework provides more features and better performance for working with a user’s photo library. See Photos Framework Reference." Apple wrote it

Comment: Updates answer , check the second link in answer may be u need do some tweaks but that will work for u