# iOS ALAsset is not refreshed after image is modified in photo library

Tags: ios

My app can take image from photo library. For the first time app open, it can take latest image.

But after I open app, go to background, open photo library and modify image, and come back to app, when user choose photo, it is not the latest image.

When I log image url in assets, it show the same one before and after modify image. Is it supposed to be same? Or different after image is modified?

> Asset = ALAsset - Type:Photo,
>   URLs:assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=4E226E36-2D9C-449C-92AE-5036938603A9&ext=PNG

```
- (void) loadAssetsForGroup: (ALAssetsGroup*) group withCompletionHandler: (void (^)(NSArray*)) completionHandler {
    __strong NSMutableArray* assets = [NSMutableArray array];

    [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock: ^(ALAsset* result, NSUInteger index, BOOL* stop) {
         if (!result) {
             completionHandler(assets);
             return;
         }
         [assets addObject: result];
     }];
}
```

Comment: url supposed to be different but you need to load it again every time you access the photos.

Comment: I call my method loadAssetsForGroup though. At that time, shall I get latest image? Or how to load again properly?

Comment: are you using ALImagePicker? if so, alloc init it again and request for images when opening

Comment: I am using https://github.com/foby/FOAssetPicker
But I init again though.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/a/35742806/4030971 instead of the library. may be the library cashing somewhere. try native code.

Comment: this is best. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26201644/4030971